# How to use x:Bind in a DataTemplate for a ToggleSwith.HeaderTemplate in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate, winui-3

I'm trying to create a simple `Style` for the `Header` of all the `ToggleSwitche`s on a given `Page` (WinUI 3 v1.2 desktop project). I'd really like to use `x:Bind` for all of my bindings (not `Binding`). Here's my `Page.Resources`

```xaml
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleSwitch" >
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.RootShellFontSize, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.UiColorContentAreaForeground, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="ToggleSwitch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Header}" Foreground="{x:Bind Foreground}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

and the ToggleSwitch is defined as

```xaml
<ToggleSwitch Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="Resize Elements" 
              OffContent="Don't Resize" OnContent="Resize Everything"
              IsOn="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.IsSettingsResizeElements, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I thought this would set the text in the `Header` `TextBlock` to whatever was set in the `ToggleSwitch` `Header` ("Resize Elements" here) and bind the `Foreground` of the `Header` to `UiColorContentAreaForeground`. Neither binding produces the expected results.

The first binding in the `TextBlock`, `Text="{x:Bind Header}"`, always throws an error as the binding engine tries to cast the string `"Resize Elements"` to a `ToggleSwitch` prior to looking at the `Header` property. Using `Text="{x:Bind}"` does the same thing as does `Text="{x:Bind OnContent}"` or `Text="{x:Bind OffContent}"` (!?). I can't think why the latter two happen as `ToString()` returns the contents of `Header`.

The second binding in `TextBlock` binds to something but it has a different value than `UiColorContentAreaForeground` (although it's always the same wrong value).

Any idea what's wrong with the bindings, please? How should I write the bindings using x:Bind?

As an aside, using `Text="{Binding}"` works but I haven't found any form of binding that works for the `Foreground` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first binding in the TextBlock, Text="{x:Bind Header}", always throws an error as the binding engine tries to cast the string "Resize Elements" to a ToggleSwitch prior to looking at the Header property.

This is expected since you have set the `Header` of the `ToggleSwitch` to which your style is applied to this string value. The `HeaderTemplate` is applied to the `Header`.

For your style to work, you should set the `Header` property of the `ToggleSwitch` to another `ToggleSwitch` which makes no sense.

What you could do is to set the `Header` to a custom object like this:

```
public class ToggleSwitchHeader
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public Brush Foreground { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ToggleSwitch Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
              OffContent="Don't Resize" OnContent="Resize Everything">
    <ToggleSwitch.Header>
        <local:ToggleSwitchHeader Header="Resize Elements" Foreground="Red" />
    </ToggleSwitch.Header>
</ToggleSwitch>
```

Then you can change the `TargetType` of the `DataTemplate` to this type and use compiled bindings (`x:Bind`) in the template:

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleSwitch" >
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.RootShellFontSize, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.UiColorContentAreaForeground, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ToggleSwitchHeader">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Header}" Foreground="{x:Bind Foreground}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @mm8! You had me at

> The `HeaderTemplate` is applied to the `Header`.

**Although this should be blindingly obvious**, I kept getting stuck on the documentation for `DataTemplate` which says `x:Bind` uses the templated object as its root. I misinterpreted this to mean that all `DataTemplate`s on the primary object (`ToggleSwitch` in this case) would refer to the primary object.

To clarify for those who are similarly code-challenged, as @mm8 points out, `HeaderTemplate` (and `FooterTemplate` too, I suppose) actually uses the object assigned to `Header` (`Footer`) whereas `ContentTemplate` would use the whole `ToggleSwitch`.

In this case, I assigned a `String` to `Header` so the proper code for the binding (using `x:Bind`) is

```xaml
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleSwitch" >
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.RootShellFontSize, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.UiColorContentAreaForeground, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Foreground="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.UiColorContentAreaForeground, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

The `TextBlock.Text` is bound directly to the string object assigned to the `ToggleSwitch.Header` in the `ToggleSwitch` definition

```xaml
<ToggleSwitch Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="Resize Elements" 
              OffContent="Don't Resize" OnContent="Resize Everything"
              IsOn="{x:Bind app:App.ShellPage.IsSettingsResizeElements, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Because a `String` doesn't have a `Foreground` property, I have to use an approach like that suggested by @mm8, or `x:Bind` directly to the same `Source` used in the `Style` `Foreground` `Setter` (which I show in the above solution).

Thanks again, @mm8, for the help as I struggle to understand the nuances of XAML in WinUI 3.